# Symfony 5 / Easy Admin 3 - FormBuilder added field not displaying appropiate input

Tags: symfony, easyadmin, easyadmin3

I am building a form using Easy Admin's `FormBuilder`. My goal is to have an `AssociationField` which represents a `OneToMany` relationship, for example, to assign multiple products to a shop. Additionally, I only want some filtered products to be listed, so I overrode the `createEditFormBuilder` method in the `CrudController`, I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003835/easy-admin-3-symfony-4-associationfield-in-onetoone-relationship-shows-already) as reference, and this is the code for the overridden function :

```
    public function createEditFormBuilder(EntityDto $entityDto, KeyValueStore $formOptions, AdminContext $context): FormBuilderInterface
    {
        $formBuilder = parent::createEditFormBuilder($entityDto, $formOptions, $context);

        $filteredProducts = $context->getEntity()->getInstance()->getFilteredProducts();

        $formBuilder->add('products', EntityType::class, ['class' => 'App\Entity\Product', 'choices' => $filteredProducts, 'multiple' => true]);

        return $formBuilder;
    }
```

I expected an Association field as the ones configured in the `configureFields()` function, however, the displayed field doesn't allow text search or autocomplete features, plus has incorrect height.

Expected:

[image]

Actual:

[image]

I tried to change the second argument in the `$formBuilder->Add()` function, but all specific EasyAdmin types threw errors.

UPDATE: I also tried using EasyAdmin's `CrudFormType` instead of `EntityType`, which doesn't support the 'choice' parameter. Still, the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `setQueryBuilder` on the field, you can use it for filtering entities like this

```
<?php

// ...
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
  // ...
  yield new AssociationField::new('products')->setQueryBuilder(function($queryBuilder) {
      $queryBuilder
        ->andWhere('entity.id IN (1,2,3)')
      ;
  })
  ;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: HI do you have any idea to filter `CollectionField`